# Reducing sql queries generated - ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to ruby on rails and one the primary task I am currently working on is reducing the number of queries being generated. I am already aware of Eager Loading for associations which I achieve using `includes`. However I am not entirely sure how to go about cases when tables are not in association.

My code flow looks something like this:

```
t1 = table1.where('id in (:id)', :id => id_list).all

t1.each do |x1|

       t2 = table2.where(t2_id: x1[:t2_id]).all 
       t2.each do |x2|

           t3 = table3.where('id1 = ? and id2 = ?',t2[:id],t1[:id]).all
           t3.each do |x3|
                .....
```

This is the general flow of the code. Tables 1,2 and 3 are not referenced. Is there a way to reduce the number of queries given this flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Table1 does't belongs_to Table2 and Table3 should has_many Table1 and Table2, I think you should add it, can't see why you couldn't

Anyway you could do something like this:

```
Table1.eager_load(:table2, :table3).where('table1.id in (:id) AND table2.id = table1.t2_id AND table3.id1 = table1.id AND table3.id2 = table2.id', id: id_list)
```